# Retrive clicked component from a panel-drawed composite tree

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, paintcomponent

I have a composite tree. I've drawn this tree to a `JPanel` width `Graphics` object via overriding `paintComponent(Graphics gr)`. My problem is: **how can I access which component is clicked?**

I only figured out trivial and bad solutions, so that's why I turn to you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shapes you have drawn, you need to store.
When you receive a Mouse clicked event:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
```

you will have x and y from

```
    e.getPoint().getX()
    e.getPoint().getY()
```

You can then traverse your shapes, and see if a Shape contains the point above. From the Javadoc of Shape:

```
/**
 * Tests if the specified coordinates are inside the boundary of the
 * <code>Shape</code>, as described by the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness">
 * definition of insideness</a>.
 * @param x the specified X coordinate to be tested
 * @param y the specified Y coordinate to be tested
 * @return <code>true</code> if the specified coordinates are inside
 *         the <code>Shape</code> boundary; <code>false</code>
 *         otherwise.
 * @since 1.2
 */
public boolean contains(double x, double y);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be an implementable solution. I try this at the weekend, and get back to you.

Comment: I just implemented your solution and it works greatly, thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with the rest.